# how to make the Image repeat in div on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi I am trying to create an effect somewhat like that https://cuberto.com/contacts/ (Hover on the silver-bordered buttons Ex: site from scratch, UX/UI Design or click on the menu on the top right side and hover on menu items) I am trying to create a same effect but with the images Like whenever I hover the Images (Logos) the logo have to go up and come from beneath I tried to do that but didn't get right way how to implement this thing. I searched all over the internet but didn't get the answer not even from Youtube and here at StackOverflow so I wanna know how to do this thing correctly and any idea what this effect is called?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated :)

```js
let test = document.querySelectorAll('.client-logo')

test.forEach(function(i){

  i.addEventListener('onmouseover ',function(){
     i.classList.add('moveup')
  })
})
```

```css
.logos-container{
    background: #ddd;
}

.logos-container .client-logo{
    width: 8rem;
}
.logos-container .client-logo img{
 width: 100%;
}
.round-logo{
    width: 5rem !important;
}
.rect-logo{
    width: 14rem !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
 <div class=" container logos-container d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center flex-wrap px-4 py-3">
            
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/nasa-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/microsoft.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/ibm.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/dell-computer.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/hp-2.svg" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="client-logo">
                <img src="https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/coca-cola-6.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
 
 
 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

BH
In your JavaScript you're setting the class name of the element hovered over (which can also be done in CSS with :hover) to "moveup", but then don't define it in your CSS

To make transitions in CSS use the property `transition:1s`, for example, makes CSS transitions take 1 second (in first class), then in the class that you want animated to simply apply background: repeat etc., Look up in other places how to do the proper background repeat you're looking for, and together with transition it should do at least something and lead you in the right direction.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @bot can you specify what's unclear about it?